# compgen -o nospace option without effect

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

I'm trying to create a command completion function, and I was following [this guide](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/tasks-reference/completion/index.html).
This is approximately how it looks:

```bash
function __my_completion ()
{
    local cur prev opts opts_log opts_import
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="-h --help -d --directory -v --version -l --log-level -q --quiet"
    opts_log="trace debug info warn err critical off"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* || ${COMP_CWORD} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o nospace -d -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
    case "${prev}" in
        -d|--directory)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o nospace -d ${cur}) )
        ;;
        -l|--log-level)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts_log}" -- ${cur}) )
        ;;
    esac
}

complete -F __my_completion myProg
```

My problem is: whenever any word is completed, a space is added to the end. That's fine for normal options, but it's also done with directories, despite the `-o nospace -d` option combination. That is very annoying, as it slows down navigation and is very unintuitive.

Why is that and how can I correct it?

Also, while I'm here, what's the single `?` for in one of the examples in the linked guide? It's in the line

```bash
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f ? ${cur}) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least a partial solution:
While `compgen` ignores the `-o nospace` option, `complete` respects it. This sadly means that either **all** options have spaces added after them, or **none**. Here's the code:

```bash
#/usr/bin/env bash

function __my_completion ()
{
    local cur prev opts opts_log
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="-h --help -d --directory -v --version -l --log-level -q --quiet"
    opts_log="trace debug info warn err critical off"
    local opts_dir=( $(compgen -d -S "/" -- ${cur}) )

    if [[ ${cur} == -* || ${COMP_CWORD} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) ${opts_dir[@]} )
        return 0
    fi
    case "${prev}" in
        -d|--directory)
            COMPREPLY=( ${opts_dir[@]} )
        ;;
        -l|--log-level)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts_log}" -- ${cur}) )
        ;;
    esac
}

complete -o nospace -F __my_completion myProg
```

Adding `-S " "` to the other options does not add the space back in, either.